# MySQL 5.0 can not drop and create trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-5.0

I'm using MySQL 5.0. I try to drop and recreate the trigger.
When I drop the trigger it says:

```
mysql> drop trigger ads_delete;
ERROR 1360 (HY000): Trigger does not exist
```

Then I try to create the trigger with the same name. It says:

```
ERROR 1359 (HY000): Trigger already exists
```

Here is my trigger:

```
delimiter //

create TRIGGER ads_delete
BEFORE INSERT ON ads
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
update params set ads_count=ads_count-1, freq_weight=freq_weight-NEW.freq;
END//
```

Comment: Have you looked for Error Code details?

Answer (score 2):

You need to drop the trigger like this:

```
USE db5;
DROP TRIGGER ads_delete;
```

Your trigger is in the db5 schema.

**EDIT:**

As OP commented that the problem is

```
BEFORE INSERT ON ads
```

ie, he is trying to create two triggers with the same instruction. (*Probably a copy paste issue*)

Comment: Thank U.But I found the problem. When I copy/pasted my existing insert trigger, I suddenly created two triggers with the same instruction 'BEFORE INSERT ON ads'. Thank U any way. I think this question should be deleted.

Comment: @Jeff_Alieffson:- I have updated my answer with the solution that worked for you. I am not sure if you should delete it or not but yes it may help someone in future having the same issue.

Comment: OK. Rahul. My mistake may help someone else. So I remained it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. The reason was my inadvertence. I copy/pasted my INSERT trigger, when changed the trigger name from **ads_insert** into **ads_delete**, I forgot to change **BEFORE INSERT ON ads** into **BEFORE DELETE ON ads**

Thanks to everyone.